# Different results between cross_validate() and my own cross validation function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

After validating the performance of my regression model with cross_validate I obtain some results following the `'r2'` scoring.

That's what my code is doing

```
scores = cross_validate(RandomForestRegressor(),X,y,cv=5,scoring='r2')
```

and what I get is

```
>>scores['test_score']

array([0.47146303, 0.47492019, 0.49350646, 0.56479323, 0.56897343])
```

For more flexibility, I've also written my own cross validation function which is the following

```
def my_cross_val(estimator, X, y):
    
    r2_scores = []
    
    kf = KFold(shuffle=True)
    
    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):
        
        estimator.fit(X.iloc[train_index].values, y.iloc[train_index].values)
        preds = estimator.predict(X.iloc[test_index].values)
                
        r2 = r2_score(y.iloc[test_index].values, preds)
                    
        r2_scores.append(r2)
        
    return np.array(r2_scores)
```

Running now

```
scores = my_cross_val(RandomForestRegressor(),X,y)
```

I obtain

```
array([0.6975932 , 0.68211856, 0.62892119, 0.64776752, 0.66046326])
```

Am I doing something wrong in

```
my_cross_val()
```

as the values seem that overestimated compared to `cross_validate()` ? Maybe putting `shuffle=True` inside `KFold`?

Comment: Shuffling can make a *huge* difference, but we cannot provide an answer without a [mre]; try manually shuffling your data before applying `cross_validate`.

Comment: That's it... I have shuffled data into cross_validate or cross_val_score and the same results as my function are reached... The main point I wanted to be 100% sure about is that shuffling only happens **before**, as we don't want our model to predict points on which it has been trained.. this definitely would lead to overestimating the score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be sure that you are comparing apples to apples, and given that shuffling *can* have a huge difference in such cases, here is what you should do:

First, shuffle your data manually:

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X_s, y_s = shuffle(X, y, random_state=42)
```

Then, run `cross_validate` with these shuffled data:

```
scores = cross_validate(RandomForestRegressor(),X_s, y_s, cv=5, scoring='r2')
```

Change your function to use

```
kf = KFold(shuffle=False) # no more shuffling (although it should not hurt)
```

and run it with the already shuffled data:

```
scores = my_cross_val(RandomForestRegressor(), X_s, y_s)
```

Now the results should be *similar* - but not yet identical. You could turn them to identical if you define already `kf = KFold(shuffle=False, random_state=0)` before (and outside of the function), and run `cross_validate` as

```
scores = cross_validate(RandomForestRegressor(), X_s, y_s, cv=kf, scoring='r2') # cv=kf
```

i.e. using the exact same CV partition in both cases (you should also set the same `random_state` to the `kf` definition inside the function).

Comment: many thanks. Is it common behaviour to put shuffle=True or False in KFold?

Comment: @JamesArten The default is `False`, but depends on your setting. In general, extra shuffling never hurts ;)

Comment: It doesn't hurt at all, it increases my r2_score of 0.20 xD I just wanted to be sure that I'm not doing anything **wrong** setting it to True in my KFold.